# css html 5 getting rid of columns

Tags: html, css

In the code below i would like to get rid of the columns and add about 4 paragraphs of text.
However when i do this now the whole structure of the site is ruined.

```
               <div class="three_column_layout">


               <div class="col_1">
               <p>This is a three columns example. 
               Praesent gravida venenatis felis sed egestas.</p>             
               </div>
               <div class="col_1">
               <p>This is a bold text.
               Sed ac tortor lobortis sem gravida consequat et vel mi.</p>             
              </div>
              <div class="col_1">
              <p>This is an italic text sample.
              Curabitur arcu orci, iaculis vel bibendum gravida tortor lobortis.</p>             
             </div>

              <div class="clear"></div> 
               <!-- Use this clear div to separate rows of content -->

              <div class="col_1">
              <p class="black_box">This is the black box    
              styling. I use it for my private messenger
               and also my group chat feature.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col_2">
               <p>Sed lacus est, iaculis sed sagittis ac
                malesuada a felis. Vestibulum vitae dictum mauris. Aenean
               felis nisl, pulvinar quis blandit et, fermentum ut tortor. 
              In condimentum nisi ut leo fermentum ornare.
               Praesent gravida venenatis felis sed egestas.</p>
              </div>
```

Comment: you need the last "div"

Comment: This looks like it could use some tag nesting, so it is clear what tags you're missing. Indent your divs and paragraphs using tabs, like code, and you'll find it much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="three_column_layout">` doesn't have a matching closing `</div>`